# Symfony security configuration, check_path goes to defined controller

Tags: php, symfony, symfony4, symfony-security

I'm new into symfony, and I'm trying to create my own authentication. (I've external auth system so I've declared my User class and UserProvider)
I've configured some routes, controllers and security yml, but when I send login form I've end up on error that says

> Full authentication is required to access this resource.

Here is my config for security:

```
security:
encoders:
    App\Domain\User\ValueObject\User: bcrypt
providers:
    UserProvider:
        id: App\Providers\UserProvider

firewalls:
    dev:
        pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
        security: false
    login:
        pattern: ^/login
        anonymous: ~
    login_others:
        pattern: ^/login/.*$
        anonymous: ~
    register:
        pattern: ^/register.*$
        anonymous: ~
    bye:
        pattern: ^/bye
        anonymous: ~
    main:
        provider: UserProvider
        pattern: ^/.*
        form_login:
            # submit the login form here
            check_path: user.login.check

            # the user is redirected here when they need to log in
            login_path: /login
        logout:
            path:   /logout
            target: /login
            invalidate_session: false

# Easy way to control access for large sections of your site
# Note: Only the *first* access control that matches will be used
access_control:
     - { path: ^/login$, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
     - { path: ^/login/.*$, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
     - { path: ^/register.*$, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
     - { path: ^/bye$, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
     - { path: ^/.+$, roles: ROLE_USER }
```

And my controller for routes looks like this:

```
    class LoginController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @param AuthenticationUtils $authUtils
     * @param TokenStorageInterface $tokenStorage
     * @return Response
     *
     * @Route("/login", name="user.login", methods="GET")
     */
    public function loginAction(
        AuthenticationUtils $authUtils,
        TokenStorageInterface $tokenStorage
    ) {
        if (!is_null($tokenStorage->getToken()) && in_array('ROLE_USER', $tokenStorage->getToken()->getRoles())) {
            return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('dashboard'));
        }

        $error = $authUtils->getLastAuthenticationError();
        $lastUsername = $authUtils->getLastUsername();

        return $this->render('user/login.twig', [
            'error'         => $error,
            'last_username' => $lastUsername,
        ]);
    }

    /**
     *
     * @Route("/login_check", name="user.login.check", methods={"POST"})
     */
    public function loginCheckAction()
    {

    }
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong? I'm almost sure it's configuration problem, but it appears that I don't understand it.

Comment: If I add additional access_control for my login_check path like this:
`- { path: ^/login_check$, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }`, I've end up with error that says __The controller must return a response (null given).__

Comment: You can update your question with more information instead of using comments.  Did you get anything working before adding all these firewalls?  It may not be obvious but each firewall triggers quite a few classes.  I really don't think they are needed.  Might try starting over with the basic configuration, get something working, and then maybe adding in some stuff.  And if you need some kind of custom authentication then the guard component is probably what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've eventually figured out a bit more working configuration

```
security:
    encoders:
        App\Domain\User\ValueObject\User: bcrypt
    providers:
        UserProvider:
            id: App\Security\UserProvider

    firewalls:
        dev:
            pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false
        main:
            anonymous: ~
            provider: UserProvider
            pattern: ^/.*
            form_login:
                login_path: user.login
            logout:
                path:   /logout
                target: user.login
                invalidate_session: false

    # Easy way to control access for large sections of your site
    # Note: Only the *first* access control that matches will be used
    access_control:
         - { path: ^/login.*$, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
         - { path: ^/register.*$, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
         - { path: ^/.+$, roles: ROLE_USER }
```

As you see I don't have configured check path for my form_login. That is because It didn't want to replace anonymous user token for the logged one, so I eventually created my own endpoint for login check and did it manually that looks like this:

```
/**
 * @param Request $request
 * @param PasswordAuthenticator $authenticator
 * @param UserProvider $provider
 * @param Session $session
 * @param TokenStorageInterface $storage
 * @return \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse|Response
 *
 * @Route("/login/check", name="user.login.check", methods={"POST"})
 */
public function checkLoginUser(
    Request $request,
    PasswordAuthenticator $authenticator,
    UserProvider $provider,
    Session $session,
    TokenStorageInterface $storage
) {
    $token = $authenticator->createToken(
        $request,
        $request->request->get('_username'),
        $request->request->get('_password'),
        'UserProvider'
    );

    $authenticator->supportsToken($token, 'UserProvider');
    try {
        $newToken = $authenticator->authenticateToken($token, $provider, $token->getUser());

        $storage->setToken($newToken);
        $session->set('_security_main', serialize($newToken));

        return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('dashboard'));
    } catch (CustomUserMessageAuthenticationException $e) {
        $error = $e->getMessage();
    }

    return $this->render('user/login.twig', [
        'error'         => $error,
        'last_username' => $request->request->get('_username'),
    ]);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple configuration :

```
#config/packages/security.yaml
# ...
providers:
    user_provider:
        entity:
            class: App\Providers\UserProvider
firewalls:    
    main:
        anonymous: ~
        form_login:
            login_path: login
            check_path: login
        logout:
            path: /logout
            target: /
access_control:
    - { path: dashboard, roles: ROLE_USER }
```

LoginController

```
/**
 * @Route("/login", name="login")
 */
public function login(Request $request, AuthenticationUtils $authenticationUtils)
{
    $error = $authenticationUtils->getLastAuthenticationError();

    $lastUsername = $authenticationUtils->getLastUsername();

    return $this->render('login.html.twig', array(
        'last_username' => $lastUsername,
        'error'         => $error,
    ));
}
```

Then you can just set up a default redirect after login :

```
#config/packages/security.yaml
security:
    # ...
    firewalls:
        main:
            form_login:
                # ...
                default_target_path: dashboard
```

Hope this helps